Is the byline part of the license?
I was recently attempting to contribute to a GPLv2+ project, where I created a new file. I set the copyright date to this year, and tried several options for the name, from my name, to "$PROJECT Contributors", to their name (no assignment was required). However, the project maintainer seemed to be insisting that the copyright byline (ie, Copyright (c) 2024 John Smith) was part of the license, and must be identical across the code base, making such statements as:

it was pointed out to me this project needs to be governed by single license


seems out of sync with the project license, [...] this project is governed by that [license]


'Out of sync' means the licenses in that new file is not, in the license terms, the one used to govern this project.


the copyright notice there is a part of the license, and should be in sync

I have been doing open-source contributions for well over a decade, and this was a new concept to me. I had always assumed that the byline was separate, and far more informational than legal. Googling around, I haven't found any definitive answers. Is this true, and something I have to worry about for my own projects? Must the byline be synchronized across a GPLv2+ project? Is there any compatibility concern if they are not?
Further context: I've only developed in the USA, while the project maintainer here appears to be based in the EU (Czechia, I think?). I'm particularly curious if the answer changes internationally.

Firstly, the copyright line is not part of the GPL.  The GPL already has a copyright line inside the licence, and it says "Copyright © 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc." (in GPLv3; a different but related version appears in GPLv2).  To require that a second, contradictory one also be part of the licence could not possibly be sensible.
The function of the copyright notice is to inform users who the rightsholder(s) in the work is/are.  It seems wrong to try to have it always say (eg) Copyright 2021-2024 The Foo Project, unless the project has legal personhood and requires that all contributors transfer the copyrights to it (as some projects do) - that is to say, it's wrong unless the project is the actual rightsholder (and is capable of being such).
When the copyright notice appears at the top of each file, it is reasonably clear that the work referred to is the file itself, and the rightsholders in any particular file will differ from file to file.  If the project doesn't like that, then it shouldn't be putting any copyright notice in each file, but instead, collecting all copyright and licence information into a single file, possibly called LICENCE.  This is not the GPL's preferred option (see the afterword of GPLv2, 3).
For the avoidance of doubt, I'm not suggesting that the "work" for GPL purposes is anything other than all the files taken together.  The rightsholders in this greater work are the rightsholders listed in any of the individual files that make up the greater work.  But in each of those files, it is perfectly normal to list only the contributors to that particular file.  Take a quick look at the source of the Linux kernel to see a very-large-scale example of this particular principle in action.
I note in passing that the copyright notice is also not required at all, according to the Berne Convention, so it doesn't make much sense for a project to try to standardise it.
So my feeling, though I can point to no single authority for this, is that the project is being needlessly fussy, and is simply wrong about some aspects of their practice.

This might just be John Smith (the project maintainer) requesting that copyright be assigned to them, but wording it in a somewhat strange way?

In the US, the US copyright office says "Works ... may require a notice that complies with Sections 401 or 402 to prevent a defendant from invoking an innocent infringement defense in a copyright infringement action." So it may still be valuable in some edge cases.

Yes, the US's sui generis attitude to the Berne Convention is fairly widely-known.

We have two different elements here.

Copyright statement (Copyright (C) [yyyy] [name of author])
License text (including disclaimer)

The license text is typically contained in the LICENSE or COPYING file, in the base directory of the source repository of the project.
For the MIT and BSD licenses, the copyright statement is also contained in the  same LICENSE or COPYING file, just above the license text.
However, for most other licenses like GPL, AGPL, LGPL, Apache v2.0, MPL2 etc. the copyright statement is not in the LICENSE or COPYING file.
Instead, the appendix of license text will tell you how to apply license, including the copyright statement. This appendix is not part of the terms and conditions of the license.
For example, the GPLv2 license appendix states:

How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs
If you develop a new program, and you want it to be of the greatest
possible use to the public, the best way to achieve this is to make it
free software which everyone can redistribute and change under these
terms.
To do so, attach the following notices to the program. It is safest to
attach them to the start of each source file to most effectively
convey the exclusion of warranty; and each file should have at least
the "copyright" line and a pointer to where the full notice is found.

one line to give the program's name and an idea of what it does.
Copyright (C) yyyy  name of author
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at
your option) any later version.
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, see https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.


An alternative way to apply the license is to put something like the following comments at the top of each source file:

one line to give the program's name and an idea of what it does.
Copyright (C) yyyy  name of author
SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
For the full license text, please see LICENSE file.

The above shorter version example is applicable to most licenses including MIT, BSD, GPL, LGPL, AGPL, Apache v2.0 etc.
However, for the case of MPL2, since it is a file-level copyleft license, the exact wording of Exhibit A and/or B would have to be used.

I like your mention of the MPL2. I wonder if the project maintainer in question here has prior experience with that or other file-level licenses

If you are the author, the copyright is yours, not theirs, unless you execute a contract to make the work a 'work for hire' or something like that. This is different from licensing it to them and then to the rest of the world. If they want to be able to relicense out of GPL without your permission, then they need you to execute a CLA that gives them that permission, or an agreement that transfers the actual copyright, and they have to be a legal entity that can receive it. You should not put someone else's name on the copyright line, in my view, without such an agreement.

falsifying a copyright statement might even be criminal. I.e. if actually you authored that code, but pretend that "John Smith" did it. Your code might be cringey, and "John Smith" might be a genius with a reputation to loose...
